# How to use colored Google maps in website without any JavaScript?

Tags: html, css, google-maps, web

Can we use google maps in webpage or website without any javascript?
Just using HTML and CSS.
Previously I used google map with `<iframe>` tag

```html
<iframe id="map-canvas" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3784.7722058335007!2d73.82234131437744!3d18.44864907618605!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3bc2953b7cc05b01%3A0x4f3556fac1a61485!2sAVIG+PVT.LTD.!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1508922847004"
  width="80%" height="320" frameborder="0" style="border:solid 1px black;" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

I want to use the dark colored map but the procedure of a colored map is very big and includes lots of JavaScript I don't want to include that javascript is there any solution to include colored google maps without any Javascript or jQuery.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you don't want to include javascript? The goole maps iframe itself already uses javascript itself, so once you load it it is on your page anyways. Also, you should not add the javascript tag if you don't want a javascript based solution.

Comment: short answer : no you can't, or insert an image of your map, that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create Colored Google Map without JavaScript.

Comment: So I am going to close this question.